# Python syntax - what do two less-signs and one equal sign mean

Tags: python, syntax, numeric

I've searched for an example to convert [WINAPI FILETIME](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/167296) values into UNIX time_t (for a new Golang project) and found an [example in Python](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/511425-filetime-to-datetime/).

Although I coded many in Python in the past I do not know the `<<=` and `|=` syntax in that example and Googles is not able to produce usable results for these search statements.

Could someone explain to me what they do?

```
import datetime

_FILETIME_null_date = datetime.datetime(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
def FiletimeToDateTime(ft):
    timestamp = ft.dwHighDateTime
    timestamp <<= 32
    timestamp |= ft.dwLowDateTime
    return _FILETIME_null_date + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=timestamp/10)
```

Comment: SymbolHound lets you [**search for symbols**](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%3C%3C%3D+python).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is taken from C. It is the '<<' or '|' operator (bitwise shift left and bitwise or, respectively) plus the assignment operator:

```
a <<= b
```

Is the same as

```
a = a << b
```

Similarly for |=.

Answer (score 2):

They are the augmented assignment versions of the bit shift operator `<<` and the bitwise or `|`, just like `+=` is the augmented `+`, so:

```
timestamp <<= 32
```

is the equivalent of

```
timestamp = timestamp << 32
```